# How to allow only ssh and internet access with iptables?

Tags: server, ssh, iptables, firewall

I want to allow only internet access (it is useful for update) and ssh on my server. I found this set of rules:

```
  sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
  sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
  sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
  sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport [port number] -j ACCEPT
  sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
  sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport [port number] -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  sudo service iptables save
  sudo netfilter-persistent reload
```

This is working well but I can't update my system or access internet. Which rules should I add to allow outgoing internet connection?

Comment: Would using UFW be more efficient? I could find those commands easily.

Comment: SSH to server or from server?

Comment: @2707974 ssh from outside (any  other computer)  and allow server to access internet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's start

Delete current rules and chains:

```bash
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

Allow loopback:

```bash
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Drop `ICMP`:

```bash
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

Allow established connections:

```bash
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Allow `SSH`:

```bash
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Default policies:

```bash
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Save:

```bash
sudo iptables-save
```

This is it. I think :)

Comment: THX THX THX THX